# Why am I getting a PatternSyntaxException in my Android program?

Tags: java, android, regex, exception

I have a Java regex `Pattern` consisting of a group of any characters at the end of a string with a positive look-behind. It compiles and runs just fine when I use the 1.6 JDK outside of Android but when I place it in my Android app's code it throws a `PatternSyntaxException`. Here is the line:

```
Pattern namePat = Pattern.compile("(?<=DISCOVERY,\\d,[0-9A-F]{12},\\d,[+-][\\d]{3},\\d,[\\d]{4})(.*)$");
```

and here is the error message:

```
4784:D/com.example.MyTestApp.DiscoverThread( 4255): java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Look-behind pattern matches must have a bounded maximum length near index 56:
4785:D/com.example.MyTestApp.DiscoverThread( 4255): (?<=DISCOVERY,\d,[0-9A-F]{12},\d,[+-][\d]{3},\d,[\d]{4})(.*)$
4786:D/com.example.MyTestApp.DiscoverThread( 4255):                                                         ^
4787:D/com.example.MyTestApp.DiscoverThread( 4255):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)
4788:D/com.example.MyTestApp.DiscoverThread( 4255):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:411)
4789:D/com.example.MyTestApp.DiscoverThread( 4255):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:394)
4790:D/com.example.MyTestApp.DiscoverThread( 4255):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:381)
4791:D/com.example.MyTestApp.DiscoverThread( 4255):     at com.example.MyTestApp.Parser$DiscoveryParser.<init>(Parser.java:146)
4792:D/com.example.MyTestApp.DiscoverThread( 4255):     at com.example.MyTestApp.DiscoverThread.run(DiscoverThread.java:61)
4793:D/com.example.MyTestApp.DiscoverThread( 4255):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

As far as I can tell, the length of the look-behind is fully specified. Am I missing something? The app is running on an Android 4.4.2 device

Comment: What is your input string?

Comment: It's trying to match the tail end of strings that look something like this "DISCOVERY,6,FCF37E10824A,0,-042,2,1109BlueTooth109A4C". It probably isn't the most efficient regex for this but I'm pretty confused as to why it failed to compile.

Comment: It's because of your Lookbehind

Comment: It looks like it doesn't think the lookbehind is closed (which it appears to be), and when it comes to `.*` it fails since lookbehinds need to be fixed length.

Comment: Try changing it to `DISCOVERY,\d,[0-9A-F]{12},\d,[+-][\d]{3},\d,[\d]{4}(.*)$` and look at the first capture group.

Comment: @rvb: It worked for the given input without any error.

Comment: @rvb I confirmed what anubhava said. See it [working](http://ideone.com/j1nh1g)

Comment: @hwnd It only throws an exception for me when I put it in my app's code. Is it a bug in the Android library?

Comment: @Sam I changed it like you said and it works when I run it in my app. Thanks!

Comment: I added it as an answer so you can accept it for others to see. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying that you have a variable-length in your lookbehind at `(.*)`, which technically isn't a part of your lookbehind.  I would guess that there is something weird going that makes it think your lookbehind isn't closed, and that `(.*)` is part of it, so it isn't fixed-length.

I would remove the lookbehind, and just rely on the first capture group:

```
DISCOVERY,\d,[0-9A-F]{12},\d,[+-][\d]{3},\d,[\d]{4}(.*)$
```